# TypeError: Cannot read property 'receiptnumber' of undefined in react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have these attributes in state of my component

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this._onPress = this._onPress.bind(this);
  this.state = {
    receiptnumber: "",
    text: "",
    time: "",
    isDateTimePickerVisible: false
  };
}
```

I have bound `_onPress` method on click event of the button which is executing well. I am calling another method `_saveScheduleMessage` inside `_onPress` method where I am trying to access `this.state.receiptnumber` for which I am getting an error.

```
_onPress() {
  try {
      if (Platform.OS === "android") {
        if (Platform.Version >= 23) {
          Promise.resolve(requestSendSMSPermission()).then(function(result) {
            // user granted SMS permission
            if (result) {
              this._saveScheduleMessage;
            } else {
              // user denied SMS permission
              Alert.alert(
                strings.permission_required,
                strings.send_sms_deny_permission
              );
            }
          });
        }
      }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

_saveScheduleMessage() {
  realm.write(() => {
    realm.create("NewMessage", {
      receiptNumber: this.state.receiptnumber,
      text: this.state.text,
      time: this.state.time
    });
  });
  const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: "DashboardScreen"
      })
    ]
  });
  navigate.dispatch(resetAction);
}
```

PermissionManager.js

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from "react-native";

module.exports = {
  requestSendSMSPermission: async function() {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.SEND_SMS
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  }
};
```

This is how I am calling `_onPress` method

```
<RoundButton
    textStyle={styles.roundTextStyle}
    buttonStyle={styles.roundButtonStyle}
    onPress={() => this._onPress()}
  >
```

Error Logs:

```
D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js:76 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'receiptnumber' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'receiptnumber' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:106446:60
    at tryCallOne (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:16011:12)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:16097:15
    at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:7370:19
    at _callTimer (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:7284:7)
    at Object.callImmediatesPass (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:7512:9)
    at Object.callImmediates (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:7523:21)
    at MessageQueue.__callImmediates (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:6882:16)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:6768:16
    at MessageQueue.__guard (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:6868:9)
console.warn @ D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js:76
onUnhandled @ D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Promise.js:35
onUnhandled @ D:\React Native\application\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\rejection-tracking.js:71
(anonymous) @ D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:223
_callTimer @ D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:143
callTimers @ D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:372
__callFunction @ D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:266
(anonymous) @ D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:103
__guard @ D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:231
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:102
(anonymous) @ debuggerWorker.js:72
```

Does anyone know how I can fixed it ?

It works when I remove `Promise.resolve` but I need it for permission stuff.

```
_onPress() {
  realm.write(() => {
    realm.create("NewMessage", {
      receiptNumber: this.state.receiptnumber,
      text: this.state.text,
      time: this.state.time
    });
  });

  const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: "DashboardScreen"
      })
    ]
  });
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
}
```

Comment: can you try to console log this.state.receiptnumber right after render method?

Comment: if it still undefined : try to do this 
add componentWillMount method and put this inside
this.setState({
        receiptnumber: 'your number'
      });

Comment: @GaneshCauda Yep. It is accessible even though in `_onPress`. can you please check updated question. It works without `Promise.resolve` but I need `Promise.resolve` for permission stuff

Comment: can you try to replace function(result) to result =>

Comment: and try to log the result

Comment: @GaneshCauda it works :) can you please answer so I can accept it

Comment: nice, so is it ok now?

Comment: sure, glad it helps :) good luck with your project sir

Comment: nice man, glad it helps,  i think you dont need this line also, this._onPress = this._onPress.bind(this); you can try to remove it and if it still works

Comment: @GaneshCauda Yep. Can you write in answer why it was not working and how => worked so it will helpful for future readers too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to replace

```
function(result)
```

to

```
result =>
```

I can't really explain the theory, but basically this '=>' syntax is holding your function to not immediately executed,

for example if you do something like this

```
onPress = {this.onPress}
```

that this.onPress method will executed immediately even without press event

maybe some experts can explain this more properly

Comment: done sir, maybe i don't have proper explanation, but that i knew about it for now